# I upgraded to Ubuntu Bionic on our server but it asks me to upgrade to Xenial?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-15-generic x86_64)

 * Meltdown, Spectre and Ubuntu: What are the attack vectors,
   how the fixes work, and everything else you need to know
   - https://ubu.one/u2Know

 * Canonical Livepatch is enabled.
   - All available patches applied.

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


You have packages from the Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) installed that
are going out of support on 2016-08-04.

To upgrade to a supported (or longer-supported) configuration:

* Upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS by running:
sudo do-release-upgrade 

OR

* Switch to the current security-supported stack by running:
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

Besides, it always says, I should reboot, I have rebooted many times.

Comment: This might be the case because 18.04 hasn't been released yet and therefore is out of support ... Sit this out until tomorrow and see what happens (and maybe file a bug report for this message).

Comment: well, it is the same story. i am bionic, but it says i should from 14.04 to 18.04, hmmm

Comment: While this is on topic here, you are more likely to get a good answer at our sister site [ubuntu.se]. This might also be a bug requiring a bug report to be filed at Launchpad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you most likely have leftover packages from previous Ubuntu versions.

You can run `hwe-support-status --show-all-unsupported` as root to figure out which packages are causing it, then run `apt --purge remove` on each package to get rid of them.

Afterwards the error goes away.

Comment: i am already on bionic. as it says, but it says: hwe-support-status --show-all-unsupported => linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic linux-generic-lts-utopic, so i should remove and purge this and then you got the bounty if it works??? :)

Comment: Yes, once you purge those packages, the error should go away.

Answer (score 1):

My install was from an Ubuntu 14 **Server** iso, upgraded via CLI over time to 16 then 18.
If yours is a similar pattern, then check out the instructions on [LTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) which made the message go away for me.

Depending on which release you're on (here's the instructions for 18.xx):

> sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.xx

After upgrading, I now see this after logging in.

> Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2023.